# Is it true that $F\cap \overset{\circ}{E}=\emptyset\implies F\cap \overset{\_}{E}=\emptyset$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $E,F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $F$ is open and $E$ is arbitrary. Is it true that:
$$
F\cap \overset{\circ}{E}=\emptyset\implies F\cap \overset{\_}{E}=\emptyset
$$
Intuitively I think this is true, but my intuition on open and closed sets has proven to be not that good. How to prove it or how to construct a counter example?

Edit: How about 
$$
F\cap E=\emptyset\implies F\cap \overset{\_}{E}=\emptyset
$$

Comment: *Hint.* Let $E$ be any countable dense subset, such as $\Bbb{Q}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, since the frontier of a set $S$ in a topological space is precisely 
$$\partial S=\bar S\setminus\mathring S\subset \bar S$$
and $\partial S\cap \mathring S=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest counterexample I can think of:

$E = \{(0, 0, \ldots, 0)\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $F = (-1, 1)^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathring{E} = \emptyset \implies \mathring{E}\cap F = \emptyset$, but $\bar{E}\cap F = E\cap F = \{(0, 0, \ldots, 0)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample including the question in your edit.

Let $E$ be open and not closed.

Then $\partial E\cap E^{\circ}=\partial E\cap E=\varnothing$ and $\partial E\cap\overline{E}=\partial E\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space $(M, d)$ (and generally a topological space) for any subset $A\subset M$ and any **open** $U\subset M$ we have:

$$U\cap \overline{A}\subseteq \overline{U\cap A} $$

So 
$$U\cap A=\emptyset\Rightarrow U\cap \overline{A}=\emptyset$$